# when i use google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient, reported an error

Tags: identity, google-identity

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  callback: (response) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', code_receiver_uri, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Set custom header for CRSF
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XmlHttpRequest');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('Auth code response: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('code=' + code);
  },
});
```

1. When the popup mode is used in google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient(config: CodeClientConfig) and the redirect_uri is empty, when the server requests https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, what should the redirect_uri pass?
2. What is code_receiver_uri? what does？

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_uri` should be only passed for redirect mode of authorization.

You dont need to pass any value for popup mode.

Here is the detailed document for the GIS authentication and  authorization flow